# flask, SQLAlchemy не возвращает модель

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

40 строка левое окно: возвращает реально все записи из таблицы (добавлял вручную, удалял) => делаю вывод, что к бд подключается и из нее тягает данные.
Но! По докам метод all() или one() должны возвращать объект типа UserEntity(в моем случае), а питон пишет что это объект типа 'method'...

У меня:
db - postgres;
flask-sqlalchemy - версия 2.4.1

У меня есть версии:

1. может быть где-то диалект к конкретной бд указывается? (я вообще нигде не указывал что у меня Postgres)
2. может у меня последняя версия алхимии и в ней поменялось что-то немного, а в доках не отразили это еще?

Comment: Точнее указывал что у меня Postgres в конекшн стринге: postgresql+psycopg2://kefir_user:kefir_pass@db/kefir

Comment: Попробуйте напечатать users, а еще код лучше прикладывать кодом, а не скриншотом, потому что я 10 раз пишу этот коммент из-за этой картинки, которая вечно обнуляет мое поле с комментарием

Comment: Юрий, понял Вас по поводу картинки. Спасибо, учту! Users не печатается, потому что падает строчкой выше (не может сложить 'method' в переменную), просто принт того что пытаюсь сложить в users - ничего не выводит

Comment: Тогда тогу сказать ,что недостаточно информации. Наследует ли UserEntity db.Model? Запущена ли сессия алхимии в приложении

Comment: Юрий, ответ на ваши вопросы: да. Мне кажется это тривиально, ведь я писал, что запрос count выполняется беспрекословно!) Я нашел проблему, смотрите, сейчас напишу!)

Answer (score 2):

Обнаружил проблему совершенно случайно! Она состояла в том, что я переопределял метод **dict** в моделях!!! Оказывается фласк под капотом юзает нативный этот метод и его легко поломать)

Comment: это относится ко __всем__ именам [встроенных объектов в Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html): `list`, `tuple`, `zip` и т.д. :)